# VS2010 profiler seems to not resolve symbols from ngen'd images

Tags: .net, performance, profiling, symbols, ngen

I'm profiling a Windows service by attaching to it in the 'sampling' mode.

I open the results file, the "functions" view and I see the "hottest" function being displayed as `[System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll]` without indication of the concrete .net function inside this assembly.

It looks like all other symbols from ngen'd assemblies (.ni.dll) are shown the same way. Also, I don't see *any* symbols from managed but not ngen'd assemblies in the list, which is quite strange.

However, all the native symbols resolve OK, like "AwareLock::Contention(int)" etc.

Also, the Output tab says:

```
Loaded symbols for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Runtime.Seri#\12aaff696a0c54773664b4c5407deaa2\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll.
```

Also, I have *not* launched vsperfclrenv, but everything resolves OK in the concurrency profiling mode, so I thought that I don't need vsperfclrenv since VS2010 does everything  for me.

I've tried running `ngen update /debug /profile` but it didn't change a thing.

How do I setup my environment so that the sampling profiler of VS2010 resolves symbols in these managed assemblies?

Meanwhile, I'll try `ngen uninstall`ing them.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Performance Report in VS2010 do you see any messages in the Error List? Without the right environment variables a component that is required to resolve managed symbols will not be injected into the process and only native images will be resolved.

If you are profiling a service you will need to use `vsperfclrenv /globalsampleon` and then reboot to ensure that the environment variables are set correctly.